# How to handle application close for a JavaFX app when using quartz scheduler?

Tags: java, javafx, quartz-scheduler

So I want to write a JavaFX app that will have some background tasks using Quartz Scheduler http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/quick-start.html#quartz-quick-start-guide

Based on their documentation you should call `shutdown()` at the end.

How/when/where is the right place to call `shutdown()` in a JavaFX app so that if the users closes the window or does something that exists the app this function will be called.

Comment: You want to shutdown the quartz scheduler if the user closes the javafx application?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 places where you could call the `shutdown()` method.

First is the `stop()` method you can override in your Application class. This will be called when your application shuts down. From experiance though, that is not always the case unfortunatly.

So the second one might be a better solution. Wich is setting the onCloseRequest eventHandler on the stage retrieved from the `start()` method in your Application class. Mainly that eventHandler is used to prevent a application from shutingdown (cause of various reasons like unsaved changes etc.), besides it is a failproof way to add a shutdown hook. (like you need)